# Functional Analysis problem: $\operatorname{Im} A$ is $a$ closed subspace in $E_{2}$.

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $A \in \mathscr{L}\left(E_{1}, E_{2}\right)$ and let $\operatorname{dim}$ Coker $A<+\infty$. Then $\operatorname{Im} A$ is $a$ closed subspace in $E_{2}$.

Be $E_{1}, E_{2}$ two Banach spaces and $\mathscr{L}\left(E_{1}, E_{2}\right)$ the set of all lineal continuous functions.

Proof.

Ker $A$ is a closed subspace of $E_{1}$ because of the continous of $A$ and therefore the quotient space $E_{1} /$ Ker $A$ has a Banach space .

the function $A$ induces a continuous $ A_{1}: E_{1} /$ Ker $A \rightarrow E_{2}$ with $\operatorname{Im} A_{1}=\operatorname{Im} A$ and $\operatorname{Ker} A_{1}=0 .$

But, what can i do after that?

I don't know what to do.

How the function $A$ induces $A_1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick $K$ to be a finite dimensional completement of $\text{Im}(A)$, then $K$ is closed. Consider the map $B: E_1/\ker A\oplus K\rightarrow E_2$ defined by $B(x+\ker A, y) = A(x) + y$. It's easy to see that $B$ is a bounded linear bijection. Therefore by open mapping theorem, $B$ is a homeomorphism, and it sends the closed subspace $E_1\oplus\{0\}$ to a closed space of $E_2$.

Comment: i have a dude here, if K is closed, then is a banach space? it's correctly asume that $E1 / ker (A)$ is a banach space? how can a i demostrate it?

Comment: Yes, $K$ is closed hence complete/Banach. Quotient space of a Banach space mod a closed subspace is a Banach space. This is a stadnard result, and should be easily found in any functional analysis book.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer.